# Copy data between two servers that are not connected

Tags: postgresql

I have got 2 postgresql servers on 2 different computers that are not connected.

Each server holds a database with the same schema.
I would like one of the server to be the master server: this server should store all data that are inserted on both databases.

For that I would like to import regularly (on a daily basis for example) data from one database to the second database.
It implies that I should be able to :

1. "dump" into file(s) all data that have been stored in the first database since a given date.
2. import the exported data to the second database

I haven't seen any time/date option in pg_dump/pg_restore commands.

So how could I do that ? 

NB: data are inserted in the database and never updated.

Comment: What you need is postgresql replication http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/high-availability.html and this question is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I haven't seen any time/date option in pg_dump/pg_restore commands.

There isn't any, and you can't do it that way. You'd have to dump and restore the *whole* database.

Alternatives are:

- Use WAL based replication. Have the master write WAL to an archive location, using an `archive_command`. When you want to sync, copy all the new WAL from the master to the replica, which must be made as a `pg_basebackup` of the master and must have a suitable `recovery.conf`. The replica will replay the master's WAL to get all the master's recent changes.
- Use a custom trigger-based system to record all changes to log tables. `COPY` those log tables to external files, then copy them to the replica. Use a custom script to apply the log table change records to the main tables.
- Add a timestamp column to all your tables. Keep a record of when you last synced changes. Do a `\COPY (SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE insert_timestamp > 'last_sync_timestamp') TO 'somefile'` for each table, probably scripted. Copy the files to the secondary server. There, automate the process of doing a `\copy sometable FROM 'somefile'` to load the changes from the export files.

In your situation I'd probably do the WAL-based replication. It does mean that the secondary database must be absolutely read-only though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will probably try the second alternative : first, it does not have any impact on database schema and second, the replica is not one as it has its own records.

Comment: @AlainEsparel Cool. If you are on PostgreSQL 9.4 or newer there is also the option of using a logical decoding output plugin to stream changes. Someone is working on a json output plugin I think.